# Strange CLK-similar signal

Tags: spi, clock, reverse-engineering

I'm reverse-engineering the data bus inside a projection clock to find out how to drive the projection without the clock. I use PulseView with a logic analyzer.

What I (think to) know so far: It seems to be SPI using 3 wires but in total there are six wires: VCC (D4), GND (D6), MOSI (D0), SCLK (D2), CS# (D1) and the last one (D3) looks like a strange "2-stage" CLK-signal and I'm unable to (fully) understand its use.
[image: Board]
On the left you see the six connectors. I connected them to be color-consistent to the colors in PulseView (white = D1). Yes, the connection looks "dangerous" now but when I collected the data it was one-to-one. On the backside there is a connection from ORANGE/(D3) to the AUTOLIGHT1 switch at the top and in fact, the projection is off, if ORANGE/(D3) is set to 1 (permanently). Here are the PulseView pictures:

[image: PulseView#1]
[image: PulseView#2]
A "start" of D3:
[image: PulseView#3]

Do you have any idea what (D3) may be or what I could test to find out?

Comment: Please inline your images. It would be useful if you also zoomed in on D3 to show the widths of the pulses, perhaps during the SPI data transfer. Do you have pictures of the board? What is D3 connected to?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Now there are some more pictures.